# Агрегация просмотров по часам

Tags: php, mysql, статистика

Есть готовый массив данных по просмотрам за один день.

Нужно распределить эти просмотры по часам. То есть к примеру за 8:00 утра, набралось столько то просмотров и.т.д.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться группировкой данных по часам. Пусть имеется таблица `stats` с количеством просмотров `hits`, которые были занесены в во время `created_at` (поле типа `DATETIME`)

```
SELECT
  DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%d.%m.%Y %H:00:00') AS hour,
  SUM(hits) AS hits
FROM
  stats
GROUP BY
  DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m-%d %H')
ORDER BY
  DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m-%d %H')
```

Ключевое слово `GROUP BY` группирует выборку по группам одинаковых значений. Нам нужно сгруппировать данные по часам. У нас такого поля в таблице нет, каждое поле помечено уникальным значением `created_at`, например, '2016-06-22 21:45:15'. Однако, мы можем формировать такое поле динамически при помощи функции `DATE_FORMAT()` и получить '2016-06-22 21'. В SQL есть группа агрегатных функций, которые работают совместно с GROUP BY и вычисляют результаты для группы. Одна из них `SUM()` - вычисление суммы. В результате мы получаем для каждого часа сумму по столбцу `hits`

```
2016-06-22 21  532
2016-06-22 20  734
...
2016-06-21 08  234
```

При помощи конструкции `ORDER BY` сортируем результаты либо в прямом (как в запросе), либо в обратном порядках (`DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m-%d %H') DESC`).

Comment: Можете поэтапно описать действия запроса, типа схемы выполнения?)

Comment: @Альберт поправил ответ.

Comment: Оперативненько Вы) Работает. Большое спасибо)